# Views exposed filter combining several text fields into a dropdown with a field

Tags: 7, views, search

I am searching hi and low for a solution in Drupal 7 Views 3.x that will allow me to combine several text fields into one dropdown with a text field beside it.

From...

[image]

To something like this...

[image]

The content type is Film containing...

- Title
- Body
- Artist node reference

**Note** I don't or can't use the Global:Combined field option since this does not indicate what areas a person is searching, and in our case we need people to be able to narrow down results based on areas they are wanting to search.

Comment: It will depend on how your data is saved as to whether you can use a dropdown. Though you could do it in a hook_form_alter function.

Comment: Hmmm I was also thinking of hook_form_alter function with a custom submit function which actually set the 'proper' exposed filter variables. Was that your idea as well.. it seems so strange there is no solution for this presently

Comment: each form input sends 1 parameter, if they were combined, how would the backend automatically know which string is for which parameter? If you need to combine these, I think you probably have you data structure set up on the node incorrectly. Without knowing more detail about the nodes themselves, I can't comment on how it should be set up though.

Comment: I added some information for the content type...